# Dial an IVR and send a DTMF string in windows mobile 6

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I am new in moblie developmnet.in that application :-

Application Should be able to dial an IVR and send a DTMF string
2. The DTMF string will either be
2a) A Phone number
2b) A string code like *21*0236661201#
3. Option to divert the phone
3a) When a phone number is entered, dial the IVR and send *21*[phoneNumber]#

could any one me link ....or code....

thx in advance...
Regards
Pankaj Pareek

Answer (score 1):

Something [along these lines](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/03/09/InteractingWithInteractivePhoneServicesIn3LinesOfCode.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what a IVR is but you use [Phone API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416387.aspx).  You use [MakePhoneCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416260.aspx) to dial a number ([.net example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446543.aspx?ppud=4)) and [PhoneSendDTMFStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416510.aspx) / [PhoneSendDTMFStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416506.aspx) to send DTMF tones.

The DTMF functions are only available in WM6 onwards.  If you want DTMF support in WM5 you will need to use another method.

Comment: IVR stands for Interactive Voice Response. IVRs provide the phone menus that you navigate by key presses or voice commands.